# How do you calculate the difference between the date and current date in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, datediff

I have a table named "testing_tables", let's say the current date is 2022-03-01, and 1 month = 30 days.

| ip | founded | pid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 192.168.1.1 | 2022-01-1 | 1111 |
| 192.168.1.2 | 2022-01-1 | 2222 |
| 192.168.1.3 | 2022-01-1 | 3333 |
| 192.168.1.1 | 2022-02-1 | 1111 |
| 192.168.1.2 | 2022-02-1 | 2222 |
| 192.168.1.3 | 2022-02-1 | 3333 |
| 192.168.1.1 | 2022-03-1 | 1111 |
| 192.168.1.2 | 2022-03-1 | 2222 |
| 192.168.1.4 | 2022-03-1 | 4444 |

I'm trying to achieve the following results:

| ip | founded | pid | aging_days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 192.168.1.1 | 2022-01-1 | 1111 | 90 days |
| 192.168.1.2 | 2022-01-1 | 2222 | 90 days |
| 192.168.1.3 | 2022-01-1 | 3333 | 60 days |
| 192.168.1.4 | 2022-03-1 | 4444 | 0 days |

Basically, I want to try counting the days that the first IP was founded, and then automate calculating the number of days. and then display only 1 IP & pid with the following aging days.
Mysql version: 8.0+

New Note: I have still some issues logic regarding if IP 192.168.1.3 didn't show in march, the count of the days still continue, need to display only 60 days like the following table

Comment: March has 31 days, see: `select last_day('2022-03-01');`   or [LAST_DAY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day).   Or maybe you should have a look at the [date and time functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html) with other functions, like functions to do some calculations with date/time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
SELECT ip, MIN(founded) AS founded, pid, DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), MIN(founded)) AS aging_days FROM testing_tables GROUP BY ip, pid ORDER BY ip
```

Comment: But I have still some issues regarding if IP 192.168.1.3 didn't show in march, the count of the days still continue, need to display only 60 days like the following table

Comment: For 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.2 it counts 90 days from 2022-01-1 to 2022-03-1. For  192.168.1.3 it will also count 90 days from 2022-01-1 to 2022-03-1. For what logic it should count 60 days. Could you please let me know the logic to figure out the issue.

Comment: from the following table 1, IP 192.168.1.3 didn't show in march, that's why the counting days end from January(1) to February(2) only and the expecting result is 60 days, same as 192.168.1.4 is shown in march(3) and the result is 0 days. Assume today is 2022-03-01

Comment: According to my understanding, I think your code will be:     SELECT ip, MIN(founded) AS founded, pid, DATEDIFF( MAX(founded), MIN(founded)) AS aging_days FROM testing_tables GROUP BY ip, pid ORDER BY ip

Comment: Yep, that's right, that's solved the problem, thanks!

Comment: Great to know that it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```sql
SELECT 
    ip, MIN(founded) founded, pid, DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), MIN(founded)) aging_days
FROM testing_tables
GROUP BY ip, pid
```

Comment: But I have still some issues regarding if IP 192.168.1.3 didn't show in march, the count of the days still continue, need to display only 60 days like the following table

Answer (score 0):

```
select ip, min(founded) as founded, pid, DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE,min(founded)) as aging_days 
from testing_tables
group by pid
order by pid;
```

Comment: But I have still some issues regarding if IP 192.168.1.3 didn't show in march, the count of the days still continue, need to display only 60 days like the following table